# Column Chart vb.net

Tags: vb.net, charts, bar-chart, axis

I want to make a column chart of the occupation of machines per month. I have this data base:

[image: Picture1]

And I'm using this code to make the chart:

```
private sub

            rng1 = folhaexcel5.Range("B2:M2", "B3:M3")
            grafico = folhaexcel5.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumns).Chart
            grafico.SetSourceData(Source:=rng1)
            grafico.HasTitle = True
            grafico.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Occupation Rate of Machines"
            grafico.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue).MaximumScale = 100
            grafico.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue).HasTitle = True
            grafico.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue).axistitle.characters.text = "Occupation Rate (%)"
            grafico.HasLegend = False
            folhaexcel5.ChartObjects(1).Top = folhaexcel5.Range("p3").Top
            folhaexcel5.ChartObjects(1).left = folhaexcel5.Range("p3").Left
            folhaexcel5.ChartObjects(1).height = 300
            folhaexcel5.ChartObjects(1).width = 1000
            grafico.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 124, 208)
            grafico.SeriesCollection(1).Border.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 55, 92)

End sub
```

When I run it, the chart is added to the excel file, but it's blank. And when I click in the chart to see the selected data this is showed to me:

[image: Picture]

I want to put line 2 as x-axis and line 3 as y-values. But it seems that i can't selecte these two lines. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You can insert the picture directly into your question. This is better than posting links, since link addresses can change.

Comment: @rainer I'm not allowed to do that now.

Comment: What language is this? It looks more like VBA than VB.Net.